# What bad can happen when dropping indexes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2000

Whats the worst that can happen if I drop existing indexes in SQL Server 2000 (and are the effects similar in 2008 R2?)?

I understand it may slow down some queries, but is that the worst thing that can happen?

I'm looking at the Index Tuning Wizard and trying to decide if I need to keep all existing indexes or not because what if the past DBAs applied the wrong ones?  What should I do if the tuning wizard gives me a much higher improvement % with keeping existing turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- slow down, sometimes **dramatically**
- dropping unique indexes can cause to data unconsistancy and thus - wrong query results
- dropping indexes on calculated columns - can **even more dramatically** reduce performance
- increases usage of buffer pool - thus may be denial of servicing some memory loading CLR code or even regular queries. Due to lack of memory can cause more often recompilations
- can cause many more **deadlocks**
- can heavily increase pressure to IO subsystem

Comment: -No caluclated columns on the tables in question.  Also, how can this cause inconsistant data?

Comment: @MAW74656 Consider joining two tables on unique column. If it produced for example 1 row of result, after uniquness is gone - join may produce many more rows. And more - if you have some aggregate functions like **sum** - its result multiplies

Comment: -It sounds like I should NEVER remove an index...

Comment: @MAW74656 8-) Sometimes indexes become useless

Answer (score 2):

If an index is a unique index, it prevents that duplicate values are inserted. If you drop it, unique values could be entered where not appropriate.

Comment: -I thought that was a constraint?

Comment: Every UNIQUE constraint has its underlying UNIQUE INDEX

Answer (score 2):

Before the OP gets led down a "never remove an index" path, let me state emphatically: Never say never.

Sometimes indexes cost you more than removing them would. There are many ways to examine this, such as sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats (which can tell you indexes that have a high volume of write activity but little or no read activity).

As always, you should test your changes in an isolated environment with realistic data and realistic load.

Comment: HA HA HA!  Isolated environment!?  HA HA HA...

Comment: Why is that funny? Do you make all your changes to production without testing them properly and thoroughly? I wouldn't be laughing if that were the case. I'd probably be dusting off my resume.

Comment: -Your very lucky if you work in a place with a test environment.  My place is cheap, you do it live or you don't do it at all.

Comment: That "savings" will bite them in the rear, for your sake hopefully later than sooner.